# Foundation types when compiling for arm64 and 32-bit architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, types, printf

Compiling my iOS application's code for arm64 I faced an interesting problem, related to different basic types for custom Foundation types. Say I want to printf (or stringWithFormat) a number declared as **NSUInteger**

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", _depth,
```

This will produce a warning compiling for arm64, because NSUInteger declared as unsigned long for arm64. Therefore, I should replace "%u" with "%lu", but now this becomes invalid when compiling for armv7(s) architecture, because for 32-bit architectures NSUInteger declared as unsigned int. 
I'm aware that warning says *"NSUInteger should not be used as format argument"*, so lets proceed to floats:

```
typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

on 64-bit **CGFLOAT_TYPE** is **double**, while on 32-bit it is **float**. Therefore, doing something like this:

```
- (void)foo:(CGFloat)value;
```

and then

```
[self foo:10.0f]; 
[self foo:10.0];
```

Will still produce a warning when compiling for two architectures. On 32-bit architecture second call is not correct (conversion from double to float), on 64-bt architecture, the first one converts float to double (which is ok, but still not good).

Would love to hear your thoughts on this problem.

Comment: Do you really get a warning for `[self foo:10.0f]`? I cannot reproduce that, even with `-Weverything`.

Comment: If you read Apple's 64bit transition guide, they recommend casting for the printf-style format strings.

Answer (score 11):

One (admittedly awful) approach I've seen used is to use the magic of `#define` and compile time string literal concatenation.  Like this:

```
// In your prefix header or something
#if __LP64__
#define NSI "ld"
#define NSU "lu"
#else
#define NSI "d"
#define NSU "u"
#endif

// Then later you can use these like this...
NSString* foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%"NSU" things in the array.", array.count]);
```

Pretty horrible, but it works.

Another, seemingly more common approach is to simply upcast the value to the larger type on every platform, like this:

```
NSString* foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu things in the array.", (unsigned long)array.count]);
```

More recently (i.e. since the new boxing shorthand syntax came out) I've found myself being lazy and have started just boxing everything, like this:

```
NSString* foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ things in the array.", @(array.count)]);
```

There may be a better way, but those are the ones I've seen the most.

Comment: It should perhaps be mentioned that the upcast is only formal (to make the compiler happy), but does not really change anything, because `sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(NSUInteger)` on both 32- and 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Auto-completion suggests exactly upcast (i.e %lu and (unsigned long)value)

Comment: I'm confused. How can you define `NSI`/`NSU` at compile time and then magically the right one for each architecture will be chosen at runtime?

Comment: The choice isn't happening at runtime. All the choices are happening at compile time. `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` are also defined at compile time, this is just mimicking/paralleling that behavior.